# Parameters for string pointing to array of strings?

Tags: c, function, pointers, parameters

i just started learning about strings and had a question about sending an array of strings to a function using a pointer parameter. Im trying to simply print one of the strings in the array but i cant even do that.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int stringSum(char *s);
/*void minMaxValues(char *s, int *min, int *max);*/

int main(void)
{
    int value;
    char* text[] = { "1 + 2 + 3 + 4",
                     "7",
                     "30 + 20 + 10",
                     "9 + 900 + 90000 + 9000 + 90" };
    stringSum(&text);
}

int stringSum(char *s)
{
    printf("%s\n",s[0]);
}
```

i get some error named segmentation fault when trying to compile. Am i incorrect in just passing the adress of the string array to the function? Help would be appreciated

Comment: im going to eventually process the string in the function but for now im simply checking if i have sent it in correctly

Comment: `int stringSum(char *s[]);`...`stringSum(text);`

Answer (score 2):

Change your function header to:

```
int stringSum(char **s);
```

This allows you to pass the entire array. What you are currently doing is passing a single string to the method, and then printing the first character only (`s[0]`).

There's also no need to pass the array by reference. Just `stringSum(text);` will be fine. This is because you want to pass the *value* of the array's address to the method. When you index it (with `s[0]`) you are accessing the address of the first string in the array.

---

Also, remember to return a value from `stringSum` and `main`, though this is unrelated to your error.

Comment: How could be this allow to pas a `char (*)[]` type ?

Comment: @haccks You can use the `char* s[]` notation if you know the number of elements in `s`, so it would be: `char* s[4]` in the function definition. You're also failing to return anything from `main` which is likely causing warnings/errors.
see: http://ideone.com/pFZ2uB

Comment: @SimpleJ; I am not the one who asked this question :)

Comment: I can't comment on his answer because I don't have the required reputation, but Joachim's solution isn't equivalent to the original code. OP wanted to pass the entire array to the method, Joachim passed only the first string.

Comment: @haccks Care to elaborate? It compiles and runs error/warning-free and does exactly what the OP wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

1. You pass the address of the array of strings as argument to the function. This should give you a big warning.
2. You tell `printf` to print a string, but then pass a single character as argument. This should also give you a big warning.

Both of the above leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

To solve these problems, first you have to call it with a single string, like

```
stringSum(text[0]);
```

Then you have to print the string:

```
printf("%s\n", s);
```

---

Lessons to be learned: Read the warnings and fix the. Warnings are often indicators of [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), which in many cases leads to program crashes such as segmentation faults.

Comment: is there any way to send the whole array of strings to the function without having to call the function multiple times?

Comment: @user3686360 Of course there is, but then you have to modify the parameter to be an array of strings.

Comment: I downvoted for the reasons I gave in my answer's comment (I only just got enough reputation to both comment and downvote, hence the delay). You answered the question by restructuring the OP's code, so I don't really see this as answering his actual question. And this isn't a trivial restructure - OP wanted to pass an entire array of strings, you changed his code to pass a single string.